# Changing the Column Data on every Data Row

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, datarow

I am trying to access the `DataSet` to change a columns value for every row in the `DataSet`.

I have pulled a `DataSet dsCustomers` from a database. From that `DataSet` I select the only table in the `DataSet`.
There is a column in the `DataTable` table called `BillingDate`.

I'm trying to add 10 years to the `DateTime` variable in that column. And I am attempting to do this for every row in the data table. I honestly have no idea how to go about this or what I am doing wrong.

My code below is my best attempt at grasping how to do this. Any help is graciously accepted.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnCustomer = new SqlConnection(cString);
DataSet dsCustomer = new DataSet();
try
{
     dsCustomer = LearningData.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(sqlConnCustomer, "dbo.rptRecurringBilling_S");
     DataTable table = dsCustomer.Tables[0];
     int i = 0;
     foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
     {
         row.AcceptChanges();
         row.BeginEdit();
         System.DateTime BillingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i]["BillingDate"]);
         BillingDate = BillingDate.AddYears(10);
         row.EndEdit();
         row.AcceptChanges();
         i++;
     }
}
```

Comment: First,  put the new value back in the datatable.  You probably do not want either`AcceptChanges` if you want to update the database with the changes.  AcceptChanges will clear the changed RowState setting so that the DA/DT wont know that it is updated,

Comment: Why don't you just write an sql statement, it would probably be faster

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            var ik = row["BillingDate"];
            System.DateTime BillingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ik);
            BillingDate = BillingDate.AddYears(10);
            row["VALUE"] = BillingDate;
        }
```